# Forçar o keypress enter ou form submit em form com JS, Geolocation!

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Galera, estou com o seguinte problema a ser resolvido..
estou usando a API do google para pegar a geolocalização atual do usuário,
porem ao clicar no icone que pega a geolocalização o formulário só é submetido se que clicar no input e pressionar enter, porem eu preciso que isso seja automático.
1 - Ou pressione o enter automaticamente.
2 - Ou de o submit no form automaticamente.
já testei os seguintes códigos porem não retorna o resultado esperado:

```
//for submit
jQuery("form#searchUnits").submit();

//for keypress Enter
var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );
jQuery('form#searchUnits .units-input').trigger( e );
```

esse código está dentro de um jQuery(document).click(function (e){});
com e.preventDefault();
então tudo ocorre sem recarregar a pág. Obrigado!

```js
                    // Geolocation Google Maps API
                    jQuery('#getLocation').on('click', function ( e ) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function ( position ) {
                                var pos = {
                                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                                };

                                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
                                geocoder.geocode({ 'location': pos }, function ( results, status ) {
                                    if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                                        if ( results[1] ) {

                                            jQuery( '#getLocation' ).parent().find( 'input' ).val( results[1].formatted_address );
                                            jQuery( '#getLocation' ).parent().find( 'input' ).attr( 'lat', pos.lat );
                                            jQuery( '#getLocation' ).parent().find( 'input' ).attr( 'lng', pos.lng );


                                            //arrayLat();
                                        } else {
                                            //window.alert('No results found');
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                });
                            }, function () {
                                alert('É necessário ativar a geolocalização para utilizar este recurso!');
                            });
                        } else { }


                        jQuery( "html, body" ).click();
                            jQuery( "form#searchUnits .units-input" ).focus();

                            jQuery("form#searchUnits").submit();

                            var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );
                            jQuery('form#searchUnits .units-input').trigger( e );
                    });
```

Comment: voce tem callback apos obter a geolocation?

Comment: Como assim o callback ? ele me retorna o endereço, lat e lng.

Comment: Coloque a parte relevante de como está obtendo a localizacao

Comment: ta ae brother! vlw

Comment: tente submeter o formulario dentro do status `ok`. `if (status === 'OK')` na última linha desse `if` colocar `jQuery("form#searchUnits").submit();`

Comment: tentei isso, não deu certo.. =/
ele preenche o input com a localização.. mais só da o submit se eu clicar no enter manualmente..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72545/discussion-between-drik-and-lucas-costa).